# ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions' Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, databricks

I have a databricks notebook that uses chrome webdriver. I had been using the same notebook and code for several months, yet all of a sudden I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

For the line:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Is anyone able to guide me to a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried updating typing_extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue when using Selenium(4.17.2) on Python 3.10.

Specifying Selenium version to 4.16.0 fixes the issue for me.

`pip install 'selenium==4.16.0'`